# What is one word or short phrase to describe something that has no beginning or end?

Tags: expressions

What is the grammatically accurate word or short phrase to describe a thing that has neither a beginning nor an end? Not looking for metaphors here.

Comment: eternal: 1. Being without beginning or end (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eternal)

Comment: "Limitless", "boundless" and "infinite" come to mind. In the temporal domain, "eternal".

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question, unless you exactly explain what you are referring to.  For example, is this about a cartesian line in math, or is it about a physics or cosmology matter, or concerning perhaps work or .. ?

Comment: The term 'grammatically accurate' is imprecise here at best.

Comment: Perpetual is another word that matches your question

Comment: 'Without beginning or end' itself has idiomatic (collocational) status. It's a well known descriptor of Melchisedec (as a type [foreshadowing] of Christ) in the Bible (AV; Heb 7:3).

Comment: A circle has no end. -I. Asimov

Comment: This should be easily searched in a popular web search. What results have you found that don't answer your question?

Comment: @StoneyB neither does a mobius  strip!

Comment: @araucaria True. In fact, a Möbius strip has no end twice!

Comment: I was going to say "It's a Small World After All", but I suppose that classifies as a metaphor.

Comment: @StoneyB refers to a sci-fi classic by Asimov and the search for the Second Foundation at "stars end".

Comment: A ring.  It's part of an old song, The Riddle, that starts: I gave my love a cherry, ...  Here is a version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OORxUZP2Ez4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boundless
```

would be good I think

Answer (score 1):

> **infinity** <sup>Merriam Webster</sup>
>
> the quality of being infinite
>   unlimited extent of time, space, or quantity :  boundlessness

Comment: The set of all positive numbers (or all non-negative numbers) is infinite, but it has a beginning. Conversely (as mentioned in a comment), a circle has no beginning or end, but is finite.

Comment: I think 'infinite' might be better in this usage, rather than 'infinity'.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word annular:

> **an·nu·lar**  *ˈanyələr*
>
> ring-shaped.
>
> synonyms: circular, ring-shaped, disk-shaped, round;

Answer (score 0):

I like eternal, but timeless is another option.

**Edit.** To expand a bit on my answer, a Google search shows the definition of eternal as

> lasting or existing forever; without end.
>   "the secret of eternal youth"
>
> synonyms: everlasting, never-ending, endless, without end, perpetual, undying, immortal, deathless, indestructible, imperishable, immutable, abiding, permanent, enduring, infinite, boundless, timeless

The emphasis of the definition and most of the synonyms seem to be on the fact that it doesn't end, but does not specify that it did not begin! So I must prefer timeless, because of its obvious meaning that it's without time constraints, which would include a beginning.

Comment: @choster, thanks for the welcome. I will expand my answer according to your advice.